# Using query as a query parameter

Tags: json, query-string

I am using poorly documented API, so I suppose that there is a common practice since they didn't explained the way it should be used. API endpoint supports following query parameters: query (string) and pageNumber (integer) - the part that confuses me is query inside of query.

For example, I want to check all orders with property that has some value: `https://api.logsta.com/orders?query=orderIdentifier=106300` but it doesn't work. For me, the natural behaviour would be `https://api.logsta.com/orders?orderIdentifier=106300` but this is impossible since they require this query `query` parameter.

Based on your experience, what should I pass into this query to make it work? Is it a SQL expression or there is a standardized approach?

Answer (score 0):

you can use url encode

```
?query=orderIdentifier%3D106300
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, and it works, so I hope that this scenario could be useful to someone.

```
https://api.logsta.com/orders?query=orderIdentifier:300000169928409
```

instead of using `=` again or URL encoding, they are accepting `:`